# Does the verb “catch” show the causative/inchoative alternation?

Tags: transitivity

The Oxford learner's dictionary has these example sentences under the entry "catch"(verb)

become stuck [intransitive, transitive] to become stuck in or on something; to make something become stuck

- catch (in/on something) : **Her dress caught on a nail.**
- catch something (in/on something) : **He caught his thumb in the door.**

Is this causative/inchoative alternation?

Comment: I guess it does.  "She caught her dress on a nail" corresponds to your first example.

Comment: Thank you. It has every look of causative/inchoative alt. I just wanted to confirm it. Thanks!

Comment: As a side question, does 'inchoative' verbs only involve 'change of state' or does it involve'change of position'  too? And is the verb at hand change of state or change of position?

Comment: Clearly, we can get the alternation with change of position -- with "move", for instance.